# Stop Sprite Animation in cocos2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, sprite, sprite-sheet

This is the code to show sprite sheet animation if something happens in the game, animation works perfect but it is not stopping after the animation frames sequence complete, i had done so many things to stop the animation, but nothing is giving me solution, here is my code

```
if(m_bEffectChangeColor){
```

`

```
        m_gamecoinffect = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"powerup0001"];
          [self addChild:m_gamecoinffect z:3];



        CCAnimate *coineffect = [CCAnimate actionWithSpriteSequence:@"powerup%04d" numFrames:30 delay:0.1f restoreOriginalFrame:NO];
        [m_gamecoinffect runAction:[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:coineffect]];

        m_gamecoinffect.position = ptEffectPos;

        CCCallBlock *block = [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{
            //[m_gamecoinffect stopAllActions];
            [self removeChild:m_gamecoinffect cleanup:YES];

        }];
        CCDelayTime *time = [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:1];
        [m_gamecoinffect runAction:[CCSequence actions:time, block, nil]];
```

`

Above code i tried to add timer and everything i know, but nothing is working,,, i would like to stop animation and remove those sprite from the layer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The animation does not stop because the `CCRepeatForever` is the action which animates forever means continuously. Change below line:

```
[m_gamecoinffect runAction:[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:coineffect]];
```

With

```
[m_gamecoinffect runAction:coineffect];
```

Comment: ok thanks for your replay,, let me check if its work or not.. Thank you once again